# Date picker broken?

Tags: control-panel, javascript, live-preview, jquery

I just tried adding a date field to the bone stock Craft news template to try out the Live Preview and I'm getting a jQuery error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.currentDay=e("a",n).html()')

I posted this on the G+, Brad couldn't reproduce, wonder if anyone else is having problems? I know the default Craft install doesn't use any javascript so it's gotta be on Craft's end? I just installed this on my production server as well, same issue, tried different browsers.

No other bugs that I can see.  Anyone else getting this?

[image: live preview error]

Comment: Per [Brad's answer](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/5066/45), this appears to be a bug with a fix coming soon. Closing this thread as a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Can confirm this is a bug.  Should have it fixed soon.